# IIS7 SOAP PHP server doesn't run function

Tags: php, web-services, soap, iis-7

I'm trying to create a SOAP webservice using PHP and IIS7.
I've created and tested my server, client and WSDL file on a VM (ubuntu, apache2) and it worked perfectly.

Now I have to put this server on a Windows Server 2008 machine and I want to use IIS7.
I first had a problem because my client was returning a SoapFault "405 - method Not Allowed" but i solved it by adding POST to the mapping handler.

Now my request works on my client but i can't receive any answer from the server. This is what i get from my client :

[image: Request and Request Header (client)]

I tried to "log" what happens on my server and I can assure you the server doesn't run the function called by the client.

Do you have any idea why IIS7 doesn't run this function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so It seems my POST mapping handler wasn't a good idea because the error wasn't here anymore but my server couldn't receive the HTTP POST.

I figured that my server couldn't understand the php class I used was in a folder so I put the class in the root folder with my server and deleted the mapping handler for POST ... And voilà, It works perfectly !

Hope this will help someone one day.